# Having trouble with React Hooks and States. Trying to make a password strength meter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to make a simple password strength meter. The issue I am having here is that my code works, but not how I want it to. It seems to be updating the strength message one keyboard press too late. I am not sure how to fix this.

```
import React, {useState} from "react";


const PasswordStrength = () => {

    function passwordStrength(pw) {
        
        return (  /* at least 8 characters */
            /.{12,}/.test(pw)          /* bonus if longer */
            + /[a-z]/.test(pw)         /* a lower letter */
            + /[A-Z]/.test(pw)         /* a upper letter */
            + /\d/.test(pw)            /* a digit */
            + /[^A-Za-z0-9]/.test(pw)  /* a special character */
        )
    }
    // Meter is updating the message with the stroke after

    const [pwInput,setpwInput] = useState("")
    const [strength, setStrength] = useState(0)
    const [hiddenStatus, setHiddenStatus] = useState(true)
    const [strengthMessage, setStrengthMessage] = useState("We need a strong password")

    const updateScore = (props) => {
        //run it through the passwordStrength function
        setStrength(passwordStrength(props))
        setpwInput(props)

        if(strength===0){
            setHiddenStatus(true)
            setStrengthMessage("We need a strong password")
        }
        if(strength > 0 && strength <= 2){
            //weak sauce
            setStrengthMessage("Weak sauce :(")
        }
        if(strength===3){
            //better
            setStrengthMessage("Better...")
        }
        if(strength===4){
            //great
            setStrengthMessage("Great")
        }
        if(strength>=5){
            //outstanding
            setStrengthMessage("Outstanding!")
        }
    }


    return (

        <div>Create a password:
            <input
                type="password"
                id="pwd"
                placeholder="create a password"
                value={pwInput}
                onChange= {e => updateScore(e.target.value)}


                />
        <progress id="strength" value={strength} max="5" />
        <div id="message" aria-hidden={hiddenStatus}>
            {strengthMessage}
        </div>
        </div>
    );
}

    export default PasswordStrength
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies in the fact that setting state is an asynchronous process.

In your `updateScore` method, you are setting the newly computed strength to the state. But remember that setting a state is asynchronous activity. So you would not get the updated state to compute your strength message, since it hasn't been updated yet.

For this to work properly, instead of using the `strength` from the state to compute your message, you can use the return value of `passwordStrength` method.

```
const updateScore = (props) => {
    const newStrength = passwordStrength(props);
    setStrength(newStrength);
    setpwInput(props);

    if(newStrength ===0){
        setHiddenStatus(true);
        setStrengthMessage("We need a strong password");
    }
    if(newStrength > 0 && newStrength <= 2){
        //weak sauce
        setStrengthMessage("Weak sauce :(");
    }
    if(newStrength ===3){
        //better
        setStrengthMessage("Better...");
    }
    if(newStrength ===4){
        //great
        setStrengthMessage("Great");
    }
    if(newStrength >=5){
        //outstanding
        setStrengthMessage("Outstanding!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you jateen! And thank you for the explanation as well. Very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

before setting strength try  storing the password strength value in a variable  and then use it instead of the hook inside function for setting strength message

```
const updateScore = (props) => {
    let temp = passwordStrength(props)
    setStrength(temp)
    setpwInput(props)

    if(temp ===0){
        setHiddenStatus(true)
        setStrengthMessage("We need a strong password")
    }
    if(temp > 0 && temp <= 2){
        //weak sauce
        setStrengthMessage("Weak sauce :(")
    }
    if(temp ===3){
        //better
        setStrengthMessage("Better...")
    }
    if(temp ===4){
        //great
        setStrengthMessage("Great")
    }
    if(temp >=5){
        //outstanding
        setStrengthMessage("Outstanding!")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input Sunil. I tried your suggestion but it did not work :( I also just tried using onInput instead of onChange but still no dice.

Comment: Oh wait... Nevermind. It does work now. Thank you Sunil! Your suggestion plus changing it from onChange to onInput fixes it. Thanks again!